# How to use "make" and/or "make for" in this sense?

Tags: grammar, idioms

Which of the following sentences are grammatically correct? Which ones are formal, idiomatic and proper to use in writing an essay?

- What makes for a good job?
- What makes a good job?
- What does make a good job?
- What does make for a good job?

Comment: Sentence 1 is definitely preferred idiomatically.  I can invent limited circumstances in which each of the other 3 would make sense, but they are quite restricted.  "make for" is not a particularly formal idiom but could be used without causing comment in a formal setting.  "Contributes to" or "produces" might work better in writing.  A completely different sentence structure might be better still.  "What are the qualities of a good job?"

Comment: @JasonPatterson Thank you and Omnidisciplinarianist for your answer. To be frank my question is not answered yet in the sense for which I'm looking. I wonder if these sentences are in "Present simple" tense, which I believe they are, why shouldn't we use an auxiliary verb?

Comment: You can use one to set the tense, but we don't need an auxiliary verb for linking verbs in the present simple tense, generally speaking.  For a clearer example, we say "What is your name?", not "What does be your name?"  "To make for" is used in the same sense in your sentence that "to be" is in mine.  In fact, we could substitute "is" in place of "makes for" and get a sentence with a very similar meaning.

Comment: With the word _does_, I expect it to be emphasized, and used as a follow up. Imagine this: Person 1) "Long hours and uncomfortable environment don't make for a good job." Person 2) "What _does_ make for a good job?"

Comment: Most questions require inverting the subject and the verb, so if there isn't an auxiliary _do/does/did_ needs to be inserted (unless the verb is _be_ or for some speakers _have_). But if the question word is the subject (_What_ here), we do not invert, and _do_ does not need to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the questions you ask:

1. Which of the following sentences are grammatically correct? **The first two.**
2. Which ones are formal, idiomatic and proper to use in writing an essay? **Again, the first two.**

However, there's a question that hasn't been asked that should also be answered: "What's the difference between *makes* and *makes for* then?"

The phrase *makes for* has a more specific meaning that the word *makes* and in this context limits its definition to the following:

- to help maintain or promote; further
- to have or produce a particular effect or result

Asking "what *makes for* a good job?" is asking what causes (as a result) a job to be good and what maintains that goodness. Asking "what *makes* a good job?" expands the question to encompass its creation, development, composition, and so on.